# Is this iOS coordinate system?

Tags: ios, core-graphics

Is this official iOS coordinate system or its the case only when working with CoreGraphic?
(X positive is on the right and Y positive is down)
[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is the UIKit coordinate space. Core Graphics (also Core Text) puts the origin in the lower left by default. [On iOS it is common for the coordinate space to be flipped for Core Graphics so that it matches UIKit.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgrect)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it uses modified coordinates

[image]

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_overview/dq_overview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH202-TPXREF101